# How to vagrant halt an environment by name, not by id

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-windows

From the vagrant documentation:

```
vagrant halt [name|id]
```

Let's say vagrant global-status outputs the following:

```
id       name    provider   state    directory
------------------------------------------------
6e16e1a  envname virtualbox running  D:/git/envname
```

So, from outside the directory containing `Vagrantfile` I should be able to halt this machine either with

```
vagrant halt 6e16e1a #works!
```

As well as with

```
vagrant halt envname #doesn't work!
```

The error message:

*A Vagrant environment or target machine is required to run this command. Run `vagrant init` to create a new Vagrant environment. Or, get an ID of a target machine from `vagrant global-status` to run this command on. A final option is to change to a directory with a Vagrantfile and to try again.*

This is the same output as when I `vagrant halt` in a directory with no Vagrantfile in it.

So, Can I vagrant halt by name, if yes, how?

Vagrant 2.2.14 on Windows 10

Vagrantfile excerpt:

```
config.vm.hostname = "envname"
config.vm.define "envname"
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a "clean" solution to this problem so I wrote a little bash function to get the box `id` from the box `name`.

```
function vgid() {
  BOX_NAME=$1
  BOX_ID=$(vagrant global-status --prune | grep $BOX_NAME | awk '{print $1}')

  echo $BOX_ID
}
```

Using this function I can now use the box's name in commands like this:

```
vagrant up $(vgid name)
```

It's not my favorite solution but it does work and I prefer it to copy-pasting ids from the `global-status` output.